# Wait for page data before visiting page NEXT 13(app router)

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I am new to Next.js.

Before that I used to use CRA and react router.

In react router I could do this thing - tap a link to another page, WAIT for data for this page to be FULLY loaded, during this, I could show spinner, and only after all data is ready for new page visit it. So I do not need to show spinners for everything on this page.

Can this be achieved with Next 13 app router?

This described behaviour is required on some of my projects. So far I only found this is Next 3 docs

*"Navigation is interruptible, meaning changing routes does not need to wait for the content of the route to fully load before navigating to another route."*
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming

But there is no answer what to do, if I DO need to wait for the content of the route to fully load before navigating to another route.

If it helps to understand what I am trying to achieve, here is doc for react router
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview#data-loading

And something similar can be done in Angular, using Resolvers:
https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve